# Un Wrap Oracle Package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to un wrap an Oracle Package created by some other dev. 
I have the Prackage created in my DB, but in encrypted format.

The reason i need is, original Developer has left the organization and now the procedure define in the package needs to be redefine with updated changes in DB Structure and logic.

Can some one help me as How can i un wrap the package in oracle.

Comment: Which oracle version?

Comment: Where is your source code repository?

Answer (score 5):

You can paste the code [here](http://www.codecrete.net/UnwrapIt/) and it will unwrap it for you.
Be advised you will lose all comments but variable names will remain.
But for fun lets test the logic.

First create the procedure:

```
sqlplus testing/testtest
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Fri Oct 10 08:36:06 2014
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
SQL> create or replace procedure AA as
  2  begin
  3  null;
  4  /*comments*/
  5  end;
  6  /
Procedure created.
```

Next we will save the procedure into the OS:

```
SQL> save aa.sql
Created file aa.sql
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
oracle@HOSTNAME:/home/oracle/USER/wrapTest> ll
total 12K
drwxr-x---. 4 oracle oinstall 4.0K Oct 10 08:36 ../
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   66 Oct 10 08:37 aa.sql
drwxr-x---. 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Oct 10 08:37 ./
```

After saving it we will use the seeded wrap utility to obfuscate the package:

```
oracle@HOSTNAME:/home/oracle/USER/wrapTest> wrap iname=aa.sql oname=aa.pls
PL/SQL Wrapper: Release 11.2.0.3.0- 64bit Production on Fri Oct 10 08:37:29 2014
Copyright (c) 1993, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Processing aa.sql to aa.pls
```

Now lets see what it looks like:

```
oracle@HOSTNAME:/home/oracle/USER/wrapTest> cat aa.
aa.pls  aa.sql
oracle@HOSTNAME:/home/oracle/USER/wrapTest> cat aa.pls
create or replace procedure AA wrapped
a000000
1f
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
7
22 55
7weeW1mRAdYVG9cX0WEujCaQghIwg5nnm7+fMr2ywFy49cO4dIvAwDL+0oabmYEILYsGwIHH
LcmmpnWE55Q=

/
```

So we copy that code into that link and this is what it looks like:
[image: unwrapped]

As you can see we lost the comments but retrieved the code.

Answer (score 2):

All wrapping is, is a base64 encoded Caesar-ciphered compressed string.  So if you don't want to paste your code into a website:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Unwrap {
  static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] charmap = new byte[] { 
      (byte)0X3d, (byte)0X65, (byte)0X85, (byte)0Xb3, (byte)0X18, (byte)0Xdb, (byte)0Xe2, (byte)0X87, (byte)0Xf1, (byte)0X52, (byte)0Xab, (byte)0X63, (byte)0X4b, (byte)0Xb5, (byte)0Xa0, (byte)0X5f, (byte)0X7d, (byte)0X68, (byte)0X7b, (byte)0X9b, (byte)0X24, (byte)0Xc2, (byte)0X28, (byte)0X67, (byte)0X8a, (byte)0Xde, (byte)0Xa4, (byte)0X26, (byte)0X1e, (byte)0X03, (byte)0Xeb, (byte)0X17
    , (byte)0X6f, (byte)0X34, (byte)0X3e, (byte)0X7a, (byte)0X3f, (byte)0Xd2, (byte)0Xa9, (byte)0X6a, (byte)0X0f, (byte)0Xe9, (byte)0X35, (byte)0X56, (byte)0X1f, (byte)0Xb1, (byte)0X4d, (byte)0X10, (byte)0X78, (byte)0Xd9, (byte)0X75, (byte)0Xf6, (byte)0Xbc, (byte)0X41, (byte)0X04, (byte)0X81, (byte)0X61, (byte)0X06, (byte)0Xf9, (byte)0Xad, (byte)0Xd6, (byte)0Xd5, (byte)0X29, (byte)0X7e
    , (byte)0X86, (byte)0X9e, (byte)0X79, (byte)0Xe5, (byte)0X05, (byte)0Xba, (byte)0X84, (byte)0Xcc, (byte)0X6e, (byte)0X27, (byte)0X8e, (byte)0Xb0, (byte)0X5d, (byte)0Xa8, (byte)0Xf3, (byte)0X9f, (byte)0Xd0, (byte)0Xa2, (byte)0X71, (byte)0Xb8, (byte)0X58, (byte)0Xdd, (byte)0X2c, (byte)0X38, (byte)0X99, (byte)0X4c, (byte)0X48, (byte)0X07, (byte)0X55, (byte)0Xe4, (byte)0X53, (byte)0X8c
    , (byte)0X46, (byte)0Xb6, (byte)0X2d, (byte)0Xa5, (byte)0Xaf, (byte)0X32, (byte)0X22, (byte)0X40, (byte)0Xdc, (byte)0X50, (byte)0Xc3, (byte)0Xa1, (byte)0X25, (byte)0X8b, (byte)0X9c, (byte)0X16, (byte)0X60, (byte)0X5c, (byte)0Xcf, (byte)0Xfd, (byte)0X0c, (byte)0X98, (byte)0X1c, (byte)0Xd4, (byte)0X37, (byte)0X6d, (byte)0X3c, (byte)0X3a, (byte)0X30, (byte)0Xe8, (byte)0X6c, (byte)0X31
    , (byte)0X47, (byte)0Xf5, (byte)0X33, (byte)0Xda, (byte)0X43, (byte)0Xc8, (byte)0Xe3, (byte)0X5e, (byte)0X19, (byte)0X94, (byte)0Xec, (byte)0Xe6, (byte)0Xa3, (byte)0X95, (byte)0X14, (byte)0Xe0, (byte)0X9d, (byte)0X64, (byte)0Xfa, (byte)0X59, (byte)0X15, (byte)0Xc5, (byte)0X2f, (byte)0Xca, (byte)0Xbb, (byte)0X0b, (byte)0Xdf, (byte)0Xf2, (byte)0X97, (byte)0Xbf, (byte)0X0a, (byte)0X76
    , (byte)0Xb4, (byte)0X49, (byte)0X44, (byte)0X5a, (byte)0X1d, (byte)0Xf0, (byte)0X00, (byte)0X96, (byte)0X21, (byte)0X80, (byte)0X7f, (byte)0X1a, (byte)0X82, (byte)0X39, (byte)0X4f, (byte)0Xc1, (byte)0Xa7, (byte)0Xd7, (byte)0X0d, (byte)0Xd1, (byte)0Xd8, (byte)0Xff, (byte)0X13, (byte)0X93, (byte)0X70, (byte)0Xee, (byte)0X5b, (byte)0Xef, (byte)0Xbe, (byte)0X09, (byte)0Xb9, (byte)0X77
    , (byte)0X72, (byte)0Xe7, (byte)0Xb2, (byte)0X54, (byte)0Xb7, (byte)0X2a, (byte)0Xc7, (byte)0X73, (byte)0X90, (byte)0X66, (byte)0X20, (byte)0X0e, (byte)0X51, (byte)0Xed, (byte)0Xf8, (byte)0X7c, (byte)0X8f, (byte)0X2e, (byte)0Xf4, (byte)0X12, (byte)0Xc6, (byte)0X2b, (byte)0X83, (byte)0Xcd, (byte)0Xac, (byte)0Xcb, (byte)0X3b, (byte)0Xc4, (byte)0X4e, (byte)0Xc0, (byte)0X69, (byte)0X36
    , (byte)0X62, (byte)0X02, (byte)0Xae, (byte)0X88, (byte)0Xfc, (byte)0Xaa, (byte)0X42, (byte)0X08, (byte)0Xa6, (byte)0X45, (byte)0X57, (byte)0Xd3, (byte)0X9a, (byte)0Xbd, (byte)0Xe1, (byte)0X23, (byte)0X8d, (byte)0X92, (byte)0X4a, (byte)0X11, (byte)0X89, (byte)0X74, (byte)0X6b, (byte)0X91, (byte)0Xfb, (byte)0Xfe, (byte)0Xc9, (byte)0X01, (byte)0Xea, (byte)0X1b, (byte)0Xf7, (byte)0Xce };

    String line;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    int l = 0;
    String s = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      if (l>0) {
        l -= line.length()+1;
        s += line;
      } else if (l<0) {
        l = 0;
        byte[] b = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(s);

        byte[] c = new byte[b.length-20];

        for (int i = 20; i < b.length; i++)
          c[i-20] = (byte)(charmap[b[i]&255]);

        InputStream is = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(c));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        int len;
        while((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
          System.out.write(buffer, 0, len);
      }
      if (line.matches("^[0-9a-f]+ ([0-9a-f]+)$")) {
        l = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1+line.lastIndexOf(' ')),16);
        s = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Developer, you can install an add-in `PL/SQL Unwrapper for SQL Developer` from Salvis to unwrap the proc. ref. https://github.com/Trivadis/plsql-unwrapper-sqldev

Step by Step:

Open SQL Developer

Help > Check for Updates, click Add

Set
Name=Salvis
Location=http://update.salvis.com/

then OK, then check Salvis, then Next

Let it add and update and restart SQL Developer

After restart, find a procedure that is wrapped and open it in the editor
Right Click the editor and new option "Unwrap" is presented, click it and voila your proc should be plain text.

We were struggling with a situation where an Oracle ASP.NET Membership provider proc `ora_aspnet_PPU_SetPgSettings` was not working like its SQL Server counterpart. After unwrapping it, we discovered a bug there and we were able to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this page: http://www.codecrete.net/UnwrapIt/

There you can simply paste your code.