# How can I write this function manually?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to write function manually, in oracle 11g I write this:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('Select 1 id , 2 type from dual') from dual;
```

And it brings this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <ROWSET> <ROW> <ID>1</ID> <TYPE>2</TYPE> </ROW> </ROWSET>
```

It is it what I exactly need.

But I want to write `dbms_xmlgen.getxml()` function. How it works, I need to see what is in it.

Comment: Why? Oracle supplied `package.function` would always be much faster than `UDF`.

Comment: You cannot see the source code for Oracle supplied packages/functions. It's a proprietary and source code is not public.

Comment: ok oracle 11g is fine but in oracle 10 I write this manually

Comment: You can't write this on your own in Oracle 10g with PL/SQL. However, you may use Java or .NET stored procedures for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always find the source in all_source and unwrap it [here](http://www.codecrete.net/UnwrapIt/).
I've already explained how that utility works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299356/un-wrap-oracle-package/26299962#26299962).

Comment: It is worth noting that @Lalit Kumar B is 100% correct, though. Do not recreate this function.